# Generate random divs without overlapping

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a simple project, using TypeScript and React, to be able to generate a new `<div>` that has random width and height (min/max 50/300px), and is randomly placed inside a wrapper (which for this example is 1920x1080).

Goal is to check if newly generated div rectangle is overlapping or not existing divs.

If not, create the element, else generate new position and size and check again, goal being to fill up the wrapper as much as possible since min/max size of div is set and have no overlapping ones.

So far I managed to write code for generating random positions and sizes, but I am stuck at checking collisions and sending message when empty space isn't left.

```
const [count,setCount]=useState(0)
  const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  var posX:number,posY:number,divSizeH:number,divSizeW:number;
  var willOverlap:boolean=false;
  function createRandomRectangle(){
    divSizeW = Math.round(((Math.random()*250) + 50));
    divSizeH = Math.round(((Math.random()*250) + 50));
    if (wrapper!=null) {
      const width = wrapper.offsetWidth , height = wrapper.offsetHeight;
      posX = Math.round( (Math.random() * ( width - divSizeW )) );
      posY = Math.round( (Math.random() * ( height - divSizeH )) );
       //checking collision
    document.querySelectorAll('.Rectangle').forEach(element=>{
          var r2 = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   //my attempt       //if(((posX>=r2.x&&posX<=r2.right)&&(posY>=r2.top&&posY<=r2.bottom))||((posX+divSizeW>=r2.x&&posX+divSizeW<=r2.right)&&(posY>=r2.top&&posY<=r2.bottom))||((posX>=r2.x&&posX<=r2.right)&&(posY+divSizeH>=r2.top//&&posY+divSizeH<=r2.bottom))||((posX+divSizeW>=r2.x&&posX+divSizeW<=r2.right)&&(posY+divSizeH>=r2.top&&posY+divSizeH<=r2.bottom))){
        //copied from someone elses code for checking collisions
            if((posX <= r2.x && r2.x <= posX+divSizeW) && (posY <= r2.y && r2.y <= posY+divSizeH) ||
            (posX <= r2.x && r2.x <= posX+divSizeW) && (posY <= r2.bottom && r2.bottom <= posY+divSizeH) ||
            (posX <= r2.x+r2.height && r2.x+r2.height <= posX+divSizeW) && (posY <= r2.y+r2.width && r2.y+r2.width <= posY+divSizeW) ||
            (posX <= r2.x+r2.height && r2.x+r2.height <= posX+divSizeW) && (posY <= r2.y && r2.y <= posY+divSizeW)){
            willOverlap=true;
            while(willOverlap){
              posX = Math.round((Math.random() * ( width- divSizeW)));
              posY = Math.round((Math.random() * (  height- divSizeH)));
              divSizeW = Math.round(((Math.random()*250) + 50));
              divSizeH = Math.round(((Math.random()*250) + 50));
              if(!(((posX>=r2.x&&posX<=r2.right)&&(posY>=r2.top&&posY<=r2.bottom))||((posX+divSizeW>=r2.x&&posX+divSizeW<=r2.right)&&(posY>=r2.top&&posY<=r2.bottom))||((posX>=r2.x&&posX<=r2.right)&&(posY+divSizeH>=r2.top&&posY+divSizeH<=r2.bottom))||((posX+divSizeW>=r2.x&&posX+divSizeW<=r2.right)&&(posY+divSizeH>=r2.top&&posY+divSizeH<=r2.bottom)))){
                willOverlap=false;
              }
            }
          }
        })
    }
      

    }
    //if there is no more place send message and dont create....
      const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
      newDiv.classList.add('Rectangle');
      newDiv.style.width=divSizeW+"px";
      newDiv.style.height=divSizeH+"px";
      newDiv.style.left=posX+"px";
      newDiv.style.top=posY+"px";
      boxxy?.appendChild(newDiv);
      setCount(count+1);
    
      
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you started to guess, you need to repeat your code (here new position & size + check collision) in case you find a collision.

But since you implement the repetition within the `forEach` loop of your list of already existing Rectangles, the newly generated position & size is not re-checked against the previous Rectangles (beginning of the list). Hence you may end up with still colliding elements.

Another issue, much more difficult, is to detect when your wrapper is "full", or rather when the empty space can no longer take any new of your Rectangles, given their minimum size. Because this step is so much more complex, let's leave it aside for now, and use a much more simplistic approach, by using a maximum number of repetitions.

With this simplification, your algorithm could look like:

```
const existingRectangles = document.querySelectorAll('.Rectangle');
let repCount = 0; // Number of repetitions

do {
  var overlapping = false;
  var newPositionAndSize = generateRandomPositionAndSize();

  // Check for collision with any existing Rectangle.
  // Use a classic for loop to be able to break it
  // on the first collision (no need to check further)
  for (let i = 0: i < existingRectangles.length; i += 1) {
    if (checkCollision(existingRectangles[i], newPositionAndSize)) {
      overlapping = true;
      repCount += 1;
      break; // No need to check the rest of the list
    }
  }
} while (overlapping && repCount < 1000);

if (overlapping) {
  // If still overlapping, it means we could not find
  // a new empty spot (here because of max repetitions reached)
  showMessageWrapperIsFull();
} else {
  // If we checked through the entire list without raising
  // the overlapping flag, it means we have found
  // a suitable empty spot
  createNewRectangleAndInsertIt(newPositionAndSize);
}
```

Comment: thanks for giving tips but problem is i have problem in collision detection. i just get overlapping rectangles no matter what

Comment: Is your 1-to-1 check working at least?

Comment: apparently element.getBoundingClientRect() stores values depending on scroll so its generally wrong in my case so i'm trying to rewrite it and then check it